# Documentdb .net decimal leading zeros

Tags: asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm saving information to Azure Documentdb with asp.net code.
When I save information Documentdb cuts endind zeros from value.

If the price has been 150.90 I find 150.9 from Documentdb.

Is this normal? Should I do some sort of conversion back or is it only solution to start using string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript there is only one numeric type, Number which covers both Integers and Reals. Since DocumentDB is based upon JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) it suffers from the same limitation. I assume that if you are using a Decimal type, you must have some reason. Maybe it's money you are storing? If so, then your safest option is to use a string in DocumentDB.

Comment: Yes, it is money. I will change variable type to string.